# Export the content from multiple 'Get-ADComputer' commands

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

Using the `Get-ADComputer` command I am gathering the count of the operating systems for each OU based on when the password was last set. The problem I am facing, is exporting the whole thing into a CSV file.

When I append the (`Export-Csv -Path 'c:\blah'`) it will only take the last command and leave the others in the console.

```
$ou1 = 'OU=Computers,OU=Name1,DC=domain,DC=com'
$ou2 = 'OU=Computers,OU=Name2,DC=domain,DC=com'
$ou3 = 'OU=Computers,OU=name3,DC=domain,DC=com'

$prop = 'OperatingSystem -Like "Windows 10*"'

Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $ou1 -Filter $prop -Property DistinguishedName, OperatingSystem, pwdLastSet |
    Select-Object DistinguishedName, OperatingSystem,
        @{Name="pwdLastSet";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.pwdLastSet)}},
        @{Name="90_Days_Old";Expression={([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.pwdLastSet)).AddDays(90) -le (Get-Date)}}

Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $ou2 -Filter $prop -Property DistinguishedName, OperatingSystem, pwdLastSet |
    Select-Object DistinguishedName, OperatingSystem, 
        @{Name="pwdLastSet";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.pwdLastSet)}},
        @{Name="90_Days_Old";Expression={([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.pwdLastSet)).AddDays(90) -le (Get-Date)}}

Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $ou3 -Filter $prop -Property DistinguishedName, OperatingSystem, pwdLastSet |
    Select-Object DistinguishedName, OperatingSystem, 
        @{Name="pwdLastSet";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.pwdLastSet)}},
        @{Name="90_Days_Old";Expression={([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.pwdLastSet)).AddDays(90) -le (Get-Date)}}
```

My expected result is to have the content of all three commands into a CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of redundant code. Use a loop to avoid that. Also, there's no need to convert the property `pwdLastSet` (which contains the raw value from the AD attribute) to a `DateTime` value. The `Get-ADComputer` cmdlet already does that for you (the name of the property you want is `PasswordLastSet`).

```
$ou   = 'OU=Computers,OU=Name1,DC=domain,DC=com',
        'OU=Computers,OU=Name2,DC=domain,DC=com',
        'OU=Computers,OU=name3,DC=domain,DC=com'
$prop = 'OperatingSystem -like "Windows 10*"'

$ou | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $_ -Filter $prop -Property DistinguishedName, OperatingSystem, PasswordLastSet |
        Select-Object DistinguishedName, OperatingSystem, PasswordLastSet,
            @{Name="90_Days_Old";Expression={$_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays(90) -le (Get-Date)}}
} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put all your OUs into an array then use a `foreach` (`%`) as the `SearchBase`. This will also allow you to pipe (`|`) the results to a csv:

```
#OUs
$OUs = @('OU=Computers,OU=Name1,DC=domain,DC=com','OU=Computers,OU=Name2,DC=domain,DC=com','OU=Computers,OU=name3,DC=domain,DC=com')
$prop = 'OperatingSystem -like "Windows 10*"'
#forach -->  | CSV
$OUs | %{Get-ADComputer -Filter $prop -Properties DistinguishedName, OperatingSystem, pwdLastSet -SearchBase $_ | Select-Object DistinguishedName, OperatingSystem,
        @{Name="pwdLastSet";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.pwdLastSet)}},
        @{Name="90_Days_Old";Expression={([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.pwdLastSet)).AddDays(90) -le (Get-Date)}}} | Export-Csv Test123.csv -NoTypeInformation
```